# How do I update the time using Streams in Flutter?

Tags: datetime, flutter, dart, stream

I've been investigating the use of streams as I think this will the best solution for my app. I want to be able to check the time at specific intervals, then change the theme of a map automatically depending on whether the sun has risen or set. I have the themes and I have the sun code, but I need to join them together.

This is my code so far. If I use a double for the controller and subscription and simply generate a random number, then all is well. I get a different randomly generated number every second.

However, using the code below simply shows the same time over again.

Can somebody point me in the right direction with this?

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:core';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(StreamTest());

class StreamTest extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _StreamTestState createState() => _StreamTestState();
}

class _StreamTestState extends State<StreamTest> {
  StreamController<DateTime> controller =
      StreamController<DateTime>.broadcast();
  StreamSubscription<DateTime> streamSubscription;
  DateTime currentTime = DateTime.now();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: "Stream Demo",
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
              MaterialButton(
                color: Colors.yellow,
                child: Text("Subscribe"),
                onPressed: () async {
                  getTime().listen((value) {
                    print('CURRENT TIME $currentTime');
                  });
                },
              ),
              MaterialButton(
                child: Text('Unsubscribe'),
                color: Colors.red[200],
                onPressed: () {
                  streamSubscription.cancel();
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Stream<DateTime> getTime() async* {
  DateTime currentTime = DateTime.now();
  while (true) {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
    yield currentTime;
  }
}
```

thanks

Comment: why don't you use `Stream.periodic` constructor?

Comment: one-liner: `Stream.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (_) => DateTime.now()).take(8).listen(print);`

Comment: Hi @pskink - thanks that worked perfectly. 

How would I amend the code to show the current time in the Text rather than the terminal?

Text("TIME -> $time"),

It shows the time when I run the app, but doesn't update.

thanks

Comment: use `StreamBuilder`, more here: https://medium.com/@greg.perry/decode-streambuilder-e60948629d8e

Comment: Perfect - thank you for your time. I have this working now. I have migrated this to another piece of code and now I just need to wait until the current time passes the sunset time and hopefully the word "DAYTIME" will automatically change to "NIGHTTIME"

Comment: happy waiting then ;-)

Comment: The stream getTime() also needs to yield DateTime.now() instead of the currentTime variable. For my case yielding currentTime returns the same exact value. But yielding DateTime.now() returns the actual time as it changes.

Answer (score 6):

as @pskink mentioned you can use Stream.periodic.

```
DateTime current = DateTime.now();
Stream timer = Stream.periodic( Duration(seconds: 1), (i){
       current = current.add(Duration(seconds: 1));
      return current;
    });

    timer.listen((data)=> print(data));
```

Comment: where's `timers` come fom?

Answer (score 2):

Inside your *while (true)* loop you're yielding the same variable you've set before. If you change it to `yield DateTime.now()` it will generate new values each iteration.

Also change variable inside *print* call to *value*: `print('CURRENT TIME $value');`.

To cancel the subscription later, store the value returned by *listen* method:

```dart
streamSubscription = getTime().listen((value) {
```

Result:

```
I/flutter ( 5716): CURRENT TIME 2019-11-14 13:50:34.318898
I/flutter ( 5716): CURRENT TIME 2019-11-14 13:50:35.323906
I/flutter ( 5716): CURRENT TIME 2019-11-14 13:50:36.328085
I/flutter ( 5716): CURRENT TIME 2019-11-14 13:50:37.332919
```

Comment: HI Igor,

Yeah - I did update the variable after I posted and forgot to update the post.

thanks